# NSProgressIndicator not showing during app start up

Tags: swift, macos, nsprogressindicator

This must be super simple, but I cannot find it.

I want to show an `NSProgressIndicator` indeterminite spinner style to my `NSViewController` to show in the middle of the view while the app starts up (similar to Xcode). Once all data is loaded (on a background thread), I return to the main thread and hide the spinner and show the contents.

Everything works as expected, except, I don't see the spinner.

In the storyboard I added the spinner as a sub view of the main view, and the added the centerX and centerY constraints, also in the storyboard.

[image]

[image]

Then in `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    progressSpinner.isHidden = false
    progressSpinner.startAnimation(self) // <-- do I use self here?
}
```

and once the data is loaded:

```
func didFinishLoading() {
    progressSpinner.stopAnimation(self) // <-- do I use self here?
    progressSpinner.isHidden = true

    showData()
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: We need more information to be able to help. I could not reproduce the issue in a project I just made.

Comment: I saw the close vote for "It's caused by a typo or problem that can no longer be reproduced.". But could it be a bug that setting `progressSpinner.isHidden = false` in code does not override the setting in the storyboard?

Comment: Hmmm. It seems to override it for me. In the project I made earlier, I checked "Hidden" in the storyboard and had `spinner.isHidden = false` in my `viewDidLoad` just like you, and it worked fine.

Comment: Good to know - I need to dig a bit more then and what is going on. To be continued...

Comment: @TylerTheCompiler: I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. The "Hidden" checkbox in the storyboard was checked.

Even with `progressSpinner.isHidden = false` in `viewDidLoad`, the spinner remained invisible. Unchecking that box solved it.

[image]

**EDIT**

The underlying problem I think now is that spinner was obscured by the scrollView in the same window. Changing the order in the storyboard did not help, so I ended up removing and re-adding the spinner as shown below. And now it works independent of the Hidden checkbox setting.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    progressSpinner.removeFromSuperview()
    view.addSubview(progressSpinner, positioned: .above, relativeTo: nil)

    progressSpinner.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    progressSpinner.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    progressSpinner.isHidden = false
    progressSpinner.isDisplayedWhenStopped = false

    progressSpinner.startAnimation(self)
}
```